# MYSQL - Find a value with date comparison constraints in a single table but multiple rows for an unique identifier

Tags: mysql

I have given plenty of thoughts on this & have spent a lot of time, but couldn't go anywhere.

I have a table like below, lets call this product table.

```
customer_id product_id    Type  order_date  completed_date
123             A1          X   11/07/2016  14/07/2016
456             A2          X   12/07/2016  15/07/2016
789             A3          X   13/07/2016  16/07/2016
123             A4          Y   15/07/2016  17/07/2016
456             A5          Y   16/07/2016  18/07/2016
789             A6          Y   17/07/2016  19/07/2016
```

The objective is to find out the customer_id where the order_date of order type Y is the next day of the order type X of the same customer, i.e. 123 is the customer whose X order is completed on 14th July & the Y order is placed on the next date.

I have tried giving the same table two aliases and joining them, but I am doing it wrong and the results are not correct. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select p.customer_id
from   product_table p
join product_table p1 on p1.customer_id = p.customer_id and p1.type = 'Y' and p1.order_date = date_add(p.completed_date, interval 1 day)
where p.`type` = 'X'
```

result

```
+-------------+
| customer_id |
+-------------+
|         123 |
|         456 |
|         789 |
+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```